# Does MIPS instruction count change with implementation?

Tags: assembly, mips

This is a very general question from a very new MIPS coder, but when converting code from C to MIPS, does the instruction count change based on implementation or is it always the same? For example, I used an equation to find that for:

```
for(i=0; i<a; i++)
for(j=0; j<b; j++)
D[4*j] = i+j;
```

My instruction count is (4*a)+(8*a*b)+4. But would that change depending on how I actually wrote the code? Thanks!

Comment: What is "the code" here, the C code (it matters how you write it but it matters more what the compiler decides to do) or the assembly (obviously writing it differently results in it being different)?

Comment: By the code, I mean the assembly, but in particular I am referring to the definition of instruction count in which is determined by isa and compiler. And basically I was asking if there was a way to change instruction counts IE write code different ways and therefore have less instructions or if it would eventually essentially just do the same number of instructions in more time

Comment: Even on single instruction level sometimes you can achieve the same result by different instruction. Like dividing value by 2 can be done either by `DIV` or by shifting bits right, value result is same (but shift will not produce the remainder). In C the easy way to see huge difference is just to check machine code of "debug" build versus "optimized" build. In assembly the programmer is more in control and usually you can tell from the source what will be the machine code after compilation exactly, as assembly is mostly 1:1 mapping of inst. mnemonics to machine opcode (except pseudo inst.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, there is almost never just one way to do something.

For example for those `for` loops, there is the "boring" way with the test at the top and an unconditional jump back up, and the "slightly more clever" form with the test at the bottom and an unconditional jump from "before the loop" directly to the test. That's a particular form of loop-inversion that doesn't cost any more code, but dynamically executes fewer instructions (the `j` is not in the loop anymore, it only happens once) unless the loop has zero iterations.

More generally, you could decide to keep the local variables in registers all the time, or have them spend varying amount of time in memory (ranging from the dumbest "load at every use and store at every assignment" to however many pointless loads and stores you might want to remove).

The "you" in this story can be the compiler too, obviously. And you (the real you this time) can usually manipulate how many instructions it emits by giving it certain flags. Typically telling it to do no optimization at all will result in the compiler emitting a load on every use of a variable and store on every assignment, while at any non-zero optimization it shouldn't be doing that.